# Dynamically redirecting a user to the login page

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have Vue.js application where some routes require the user to be logged in, whereas others (such as the login page) are public.

```
created() {
    let context = this;
    context.axios.create({withCredentials: true}).get(`${context.$store.getters.getApiUrl}/session/`).then(response => {
      context.$store.commit('loginUser');
      context.$store.commit('setUser', response.data.data);
    }, error => { 
       /* 
          This indicates a 401 unathorized response that indicates 
          the session cookie has expired
       */
      context.$store.commit('logoutUser')
    });
},
computed: {
    authorized: {
        get: function() {
            let authenticated = this.$store.getters.getUserAuthStatus;
            let route = this.$route;
            if (authenticated !== true && route.meta.requiresLogin === true) {
              return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
},
watch: {
    authorized: function(val) {
        if (val === false) {
            this.$router.push('/signin');
            this.$store.commit('setGlobalInfo', 'Please sign in first.');
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, when the user opens the app, I send a request to a protected route on the server. Depending on the response, I either log the user in (and set Vuex `authenticated` status to `true`) or log them out.

I added the watcher because I want to automatically redirect the user to `login` if the `authorized` computed property changes. However I haven't gotten it to work. The `authorized` property computes correctly, but the watcher function never triggers.

My understanding is that you can watch computed properties in Vue as long as you give them the same name (i.e. "authorized"). Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I needed to set `deep: true` on the watcher.

```
computed: {
    authorized: {
        let authenticated = this.$store.getters.getUserAuthStatus;
        let route = this.$route;
        if (authenticated !== true && route.meta.requiresLogin === true) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
},
watch: {
    authorized: {
        handler: function(val) {
            if (val === false) {
                this.$router.push('/signin');
                this.$store.commit('setGlobalInfo', 'Please sign in first.');
            }
        },
        deep: true;
}
```